# How to get the current TTS Engine?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In a device with multiple TTS engines, users can select which engine to use after following codes.

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction( TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA );
startActivityForResult( checkIntent, CHECK_TTS_DATA );
```

Is there any way to know which engine the user choose?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=google%2Fbrailleback%2Fbrailleback-master%2Fbraille%2Flibraries%2Futils%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgooglecode%2Feyesfree%2Futils%2FTtsEngineUtils.java#

You can use the method getDefaultEngine from class TtsEngineUtils

```
    public static String getDefaultEngine(Context context) {
        final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        final String defaultEngine = Settings.Secure.getString(
                resolver, Settings.Secure.TTS_DEFAULT_SYNTH);
        if (isEngineInstalled(context, defaultEngine)) {
            return defaultEngine;
        }

        // Fall back on the highest-ranked system engine.
        final TtsEngineInfo engine = getHighestRankedEngine(context);
        if (engine != null) {
            return engine.name;
        }

        return null;
    }
```